# how to display validation errors from another form submit

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, spring-4

Imagine a form with a single field where the user provides their email. On POST, the controller action method sends a confirmation code to that email and displays a **second** form in which the user is supposed to enter the confirmation code they received. If the code does not match I then return the original view and I would like to display an error message next to the email ("email was not confirmed").

Sample code below:

### 1st view (asking the email)

```
<div>
  Please provide the following information to sign-up:
  <form:form modelAttribute="newAccountInfo" action="signup-submit.do" method="POST">
      <div><form:label path="email">Email:</form:label>
      <form:input type="text" path="email"/><form:errors path="email" cssClass="error" element="div"/>
      </div>
...
```

### 1st view controller method

```
@RequestMapping(path="/signup-submit", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String signupSubmit(HttpServletRequest request
                           , @ModelAttribute("newAccountInfo") @Valid NewAccountInfo newAccountInfo
                           , BindingResult result
                           , Model model) {
    String confirmCode = generateRandomSecret();
    // send confirmCode by email to newAccountInfo.email (omitted)
    model.addAttribute("emailConfirmation"  , new EmailConfirmation());
    request.getSession().setAttribute("newAccountInfo", newAccountInfo);
    request.getSession(false).setAttribute("email-code", confirmCode);
    return View.SIGNUP_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION.name;
}
```

### 2nd view (asking the confirmation code)

```
<div>
  Enter the confirmation code that was sent to your email:
  <form:form modelAttribute="emailConfirmation" action="signup-email-confirmation-submit.do" method="POST">
    <form:label path="code">Confirmation code:</form:label>
    <form:input type="text" path="code"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form:form>
```

### 2nd view controller method

```
@RequestMapping(path="/signup-email-confirmation-submit", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String signupEmailConfirmationSubmit(
    @ModelAttribute("emailConfirmation") EmailConfirmation emailConfirmation
    , BindingResult result
    , Model model) {
    if (emailConfirmation.getCode().equals(request.getSession(false).getAttribute("email-code")))
        return View.SIGNUP_SUCCESS.name;
     else {
        model.addAttribute("newAccountInfo", request.getSession(false).getAttribute("newAccountInfo"));
        request.getSession(false).invalidate();
        // TODO - what should I do here ?
        return View.SIGNUP.name;
     }
```

Assuming the confirmation code was not correctly entered, what should I do in the second view controller method so that when the first view is displayed (for the second time), there is a field validation error message next to the email with description "email was not confirmed" ?

In the line marked with the TODO comment I 've tried the following:

```
result.rejectValue("email", null, "email was not confirmed");
```

… but that results in the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'email' of bean class [EmailConfirmation]: Bean property 'email' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

(which makes sense as the email is not a field of `EmailConfirmation`).

However, the below also fails (silently, without an exception, the 1st view is displayed, I just don't see the validation error message):

```
result.addError(new FieldError("newAccountInfo", "email", "email could not be confirmed"));
```

In the end, the only way I could get this to work was to add a custom model property by adding the following (in the `TODO` line of the second view controller method always):

```
model.addAttribute("emailConfirmationError", true);
```

… and then modifying the 1st view as follows:

```
<div><form:label path="email">Email:</form:label>
<form:input type="text" path="email"/>
<form:errors path="email" cssClass="error" element="div"/>
    <c:if test="${not empty emailConfirmationError}">
        <span class="error">The email could not be confirmed</span>
    </c:if>
 </div>
```

The above succeeds but feels like a hack as I am not using the validation machinery of Spring MVC.

My questions are:

1. what is the idiomatic way to achieve the above
2. are there any other flawed mental models or misunderstandings present in the above code?